# Where is the context parameter in the current Node.js AWS Lambda function template?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I was looking at a tutorial on writing a Lambda function in AWS using Node.js version 8. The template code shown in the tutorial when a new function is created looks like

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    //
};
```

but when I create one in my console using Node.js 14.x runtime, there is no context parameter.

Will the anonymous function accept a context parameter? What is the significance of it not being included in the later version of Node.js?

Comment: The second parameter always is the `context`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `context` parameter can be omitted. But if you need it, it has to be the second parameter.

So both of these are fine:

```js
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {};
```

and without `context`:

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {};
```

You can read more about NodeJS handlers and context in the official AWS documentation:

1. [AWS Lambda function handler in Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html)
2. [AWS Lambda context object in Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-context.html)